# .Net - Assembly Binding is not working for Newtonsoft in net461

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dll, nopcommerce

I'm working on top of NopCommerce Ecommerce Web Application. Currently, entire solution is using Newtonsoft 10.0.3. I'm developing a plugin which requires Newtonsoft 12.0.1. So I cannot update my newtonsoft through out the solution. This can be achieved through assembly binding. But not sure, why it is not working for me.

Error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Approaches Tried** :

1. Added below configuration in web.config of root project.

   ```
   <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
       <codeBase version="10.0.3" href="Newtonsoft\v10.0.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
       <codeBase version="12.0.1" href="Newtonsoft\v12.0.1\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   ```
2. Tried playing with Auto Generate Binding of Project by setting it to true/false.

[image: Auto Generate Binding]

Is there something special I need to do for Framework - Net461 (.Netcore) ?
Or I'm missing something silly?

Comment: note: assembly-binding over *majors* (from 10.whatever to 12.whatever) is always a bit risky; in semver terms, you probably shouldn't *expect* that to work; it *might*, but it absolutely isn't guaranteed (that's the entire point of semver); however, you don't actually have a version redirect there; have you tried adding `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />` ?

Comment: yeah, i tried <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.3" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `bin` folder in `Presentation/Nop.Web/Plugins` and before trying to load plugins, nopCommerce copies the dlls of plugins in it. It is a common problem that if two or more plugins use a dll with the same name, all of them except the last one will be replaced by the others. So, I think if you check dlls in that folders you cannot find an assembly with the desired version. The solution can be chosen from these:

1. Try to use the same assembly as nopCommerce does, when in Rome, do as the Romans do!
2. Do not use nuget, copy dll file in your plugin, rename it and reference to it as a file

Answer (score 0):

in approach 1, you don't actually have the redirect; try adding it, i.e.

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
        culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  <!-- whatever else you need here -->    
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I tried it but couldn't help... Instead, I was redirecting to 10.0.3

<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.3" />

Comment: @VireshMathad that's... horrible; "hey, I know you wanted v12, but ssh, here's v10 - just pretend you didn't notice!"; that's a recipe for runtime failure even if it loaded. Going from low to high is usually reasonable; going from high to low... that's pure evil.

Comment: True., just for testing I tried it. It didn't work. Basically my requirement is to have 2 dlls in a solution.

Comment: But in .Net4.5 Framework, this can be achieved with below configuration.

 <codeBase version="10.0.3" href="Newtonsoft\v10.0.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
    <codeBase version="12.0.1" href="Newtonsoft\v12.0.1\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />